# Custom arguments/variables passed to Android emulator

Tags: java, android, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

I'd like to pass an argument to the android emulator launched via Eclipse. This argument is a custom one that I would use to determine if the server's address to connect to is either "localhost" or "myserverdomain.com". This is because I don't want to have two binaries, or two versions, of the same program, whenever I run the program in production or in local test environment.

In plain Java, I can use the command line arguments for that matter, and retrieve them in the `main()`, or also use the custom environment variables and retrieve them with `System.getProperty()`.

I can't find any similar feature in Android. Do you know any please ?

Comment: Is the information you're trying to find is whether you're on an emulator or real device, or the hostname of the device?

Comment: no i need to pass my own variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible, although I haven't tried to do it via Eclipse.

From the command-line you can use [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to launch [a shell](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/ADB_Shell_Command_Reference) and run an application with parameters.

For example,

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.caoilte.MyActivity -e SOME_KEY some_value -e SOME_OTHER_KEY some_other_value
```

will start my activity with extras that I can extract from the bundle like so,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    String someKey = null;
    String someOtherKey = null;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        jsEnv = extras.getString("SOME_KEY");
        serverEnv = extras.getString("SOME_OTHER_KEY");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you start an emulator to debug your app its like installing on a device. The emulator is not just a mechanism to run your app, it is almost a phone. Creating a command line option to pass data to your app would be a bit complicated as there is no `main(String[])` and it would need several options as to who when and how you want the command line options delivered.

Telling a app which server to run against can be accomplished a couple different ways. First you can set it as a [String resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). Second you can detect which device you're running on with [Build.PRODUCT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#PRODUCT) and other [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) values. There is also a few options with using [NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html). Additionally why you're developing your app you could let the user decide with a [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) or [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) with [debugging](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected%28%29) as a trigger.

Comment: There is no mechanism to pass an emulator command line argument to an app via the emulator's command line or to set an environment variable.